# Unity FindGameObjectsWithTag

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tag");
```

По какому алгоритму он ищет? Когда на сцене 15 объектов, он возвращает массив с ними. Если повторить - возвращает в такой же последовательности. Если поменять объекты на сцене местами - такая же последовательность. Переименовать объекты - так же.

Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы данный метод искал объекты именно в заданной последовательности? Т.е. допустим этот объект он бы поставил первым, этот вторым..

Comment: _чисто на домыслах_ в порядке инициализации (добавления объектов). А судя по документации порядок не гарантируется. Т.е. может на основе какого-нибудь хеш-значения (адреса к примеру) и так далее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Collection.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using UnityEngine;
public class YourFindClass: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Find() {
        GameObject[] array = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("yourTag");
        List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>(array);
        list = list.OrderBy(value => value.GetComponent <yourIDScript>().id).Reverse().ToList();
        //или
        list = list.OrderBy(value => value.name).ToList();//сортировать по имени объекта
    }
}
```

в результате получите лист GameObject от большего к меньшему по ID. можете пробежать по листу и "вырывать" из него необходимые объекты.
Любо использовать **Dictionary**

```
void Find() {
     GameObject[] array = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("help");
     List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>(array);
     list = list.OrderBy(value => value.GetComponent <yourScript>().id).Reverse().ToList();
     Dictionary<string, GameObject> lists = new Dictionary<int, GameObject>();
     foreach (yourScript item in list) {
         lists.Add(item.id, item.gameObject);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag перебирает все объекты сверху вниз в иерархии сцены